# Tmux statusline with different status-interval for different scripts

Tags: tmux, statusline

My `tmux.conf` uses three shell scripts to show system usage, CPU/GPU/HDD temperatures, and current weather on the right-side of the tmux statusline (image attached). I'd like to use different `status-interval` times for each of these scripts, if possible. In particular, I'd like the API calls to OpenWeatherMap, managed by the `weather.sh` script, to be updated every 10min (OpenWeatherMap's default update time), and the other two, managed by `sysload.sh` and `systemp.sh`, to be updated every 5sec. Right now I have a single `status-interval` of 60sec declared at the top of the statusline script, which updates the entire statusline every 1min - not what I want. The relevant portion of the `tmux.conf` is pasted below. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
set -g status-interval 60
...rest of statusline codes...
set -g status-right "#[fg=green,bg=default,bright]#($HOME/.config/tmux/sysload.sh)"
set -ag status-right "#[fg=grey80,bg=default,bright] | "
set -ag status-right "#[fg=pink3,bg=default,bright]#($HOME/.config/tmux/systemp.sh)"
set -ag status-right "#[fg=grey80,bg=default,bright] | "
set -ag status-right "#[fg=#7aa2f7,bg=default,bright]#($HOME/.config/tmux/weather.sh)"
set -ag status-right "#[fg=grey80,bg=default,bright] | "
set -ag status-right "#[fg=#565f89,bg=default]%b %d (%a) %H:%M#[default]"
```

UPDATE: I've attempted the following changes to this code: removed the `status-interval` line at the top, and added `--interval <n>` after the script name in each line. I'm not sure if this is correct though:

```
set -g status-right "#[fg=green,bg=default,bright]#($HOME/.config/tmux/sysload.sh --interval 5)"
set -ag status-right "#[fg=grey80,bg=default,bright] | "
set -ag status-right "#[fg=pink3,bg=default,bright]#($HOME/.config/tmux/systemp.sh --interval 5)"
set -ag status-right "#[fg=grey80,bg=default,bright] | "
set -ag status-right "#[fg=#7aa2f7,bg=default,bright]#($HOME/.config/tmux/weather.sh --interval 600)"
set -ag status-right "#[fg=grey80,bg=default,bright] | "
set -ag status-right "#[fg=#565f89,bg=default]%b %d (%a) %H:%M#[default]"
```

UPDATE#2: I followed Jeremy's suggestion in the comment below to cache weather script's output every 10min interval, which solves the problem.

[image]

Comment: You could always have the weather script cache the API result and last time of execution and only re-execute if enough time has passed, regardless of how often the script is called.

Comment: Thanks @jeremysprofile, this is exactly the kind of suggestion I was looking for. I have added a note in my post accepting your suggestion.

Comment: @Manojit How did you cache the weather script call? I can do it by writing a file to `/tmp` or something, but is there a command-line caching utility that makes this easy?

Comment: @Sasgorilla I am not aware of any utility, so yes I write weather data to a file in `/tmp` and update it every 10min.